# Raise error on unpermitted parameters rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently trying to implement raising an error when unpermitted parameters are posted in my RoR back-end. I included

```
  config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

in my development.rb configuration. Now, for example I have in one of my controllers:

```
def apiary_params
    params.require(:apiary).permit(:name, :municipality, :prefecture, :latitude, :longitude, :numberofbeehives, :notes)
end
```

If I now try posting another parameter lets say "apiary[asdf]" then an internal server error is raised correctly. However if I try posting a random "asdf" param not in the apiary hash, then the request is handled without an error. Does that mean that the random "asdf" and whatever other parameter not in the apiary is permitted? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those extra parameters are not permitted - they're silently discarded.

You're only calling `permit` on `params.require(:apiary)`, that is, `params[:apiary]`, so only extra attributes inside that hash will raise an exception.

As soon as you make that `params.require` call, then all other params submitted become irrelevant for the return value of this method. You're only dealing with data inside that `params[:apiary]` hash, and that is what will be returned.